# How to pass flags to D8 tool?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-multidex, android-d8

**D8** is a command line tool that Android Studio and the Android Gradle Plugin use to compile project's Java bytecode into DEX bytecode. 
This command has [several options](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/d8) :

**--output path**,
  **--file-per-class**,
  **--no-desugaring**, **--main-dex-list** etc.

I have several questions:

1. How to pass this flags to d8 from gradle build file?
2. How to view full d8 command (with all flags) which Android Studio actualy use when it builds apk.

I already tried to use [DexOptions command](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DexOptions.html) with `additionalParameters` property.

```
android {
    ....
    dexOptions {
        additionalParameters = ['--main-dex-list=mylist.txt']
    }
}
```

But it looks like it doesn't work.

Before **D8** tool there was **DX** tool. Params can be sent to DX like this:
[image]
But now this doesn't work. Probably because of now `D8` dexing task name doesn't starts with `dex` word.

I also noticed that there is property `android.enableD8.desugaring=true` which can be declared in `gradle.properties` file. I assume that this property turns on **--no-desugaring** flag of `D8`.

If so maybe other properties also can be set throught `gradle.properties` file? Is there a documentation of all available `android.enableD8.*` properties ?

**UPDATE:**

There is [`multiDexKeepFile`](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType:multiDexKeepFile) property which can be declared in each BuildType block. It looks like this property does exactly what **--main-dex-list** flag of **D8** does. Ok, but what about other flags?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this? I have a similar issue.